# Generate a random integer with a specified number of digits Java

Tags: java, random

I ran into this problem today and I'm sure there is an elegant solution I am not thinking of.

Let's say I want to generate a random integer(or long) in Java with a specified number of digits, where this number of digits can change.

I.e. pass in a number of digits into a method, and return a random number with the specified number of digits

Ex.) N = 3, generate a random number between 100-999; N = 4, generate a random number between 1000-9999

```
private long generateRandomNumber(int n){

/*Generate a random number with n number of digits*/

}
```

My attempt so far (this works, but it seems messy)

```
private long generateRandomNumber(int n){

    String randomNumString = "";

    Random r = new Random();

    //Generate the first digit from 1-9
    randomNumString += (r.nextInt(9) + 1);

    //Generate the remaining digits between 0-9
    for(int x = 1; x < n; x++){
        randomNumString += r.nextInt(9);
    }

    //Parse and return
    return Long.parseLong(randomNumString);

}
```

Is there a better/more efficient solution than this?

*There are lots of solutions for generating random numbers in a specified range, I was more curious on the best way to generate random numbers given a set number of digits, as well as making the solution robust enough to handle any number of digits.

I did not want to have to pass in a min and max, but rather just the number of digits needed

Comment: I like your approach though, as it doesn't get constraint by LONG length, other than you cast it to long.

Comment: @aetheria updated to show why its not a duplicate

Comment: @aetheria can you explain to me why this is a duplicate? This is a completely different question than the one you reference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
private long generateRandomNumber(int n) {
    long min = (long) Math.pow(10, n - 1);
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(min, min * 10);
}
```

`nextLong` produces random numbers between lower bound inclusive and upper bound exclusive so calling it with parameters `(1_000, 10_000)` for example results in numbers 1000 to 9999.
Old `Random` did not get those nice new features unfortunately. But there is basically no reason to continue to use it anyways.

Comment: Ah. I missed this method, although it uses the same idea of bounds checking: `while (r < origin || r >= bound)`

Comment: I was unaware of the ThreadLocalRandom. Do you recommend using this for random number generation in general?

Comment: @TonyScialo yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396033/random-over-threadlocalrandom (that is unless you need secure random)

Answer (score 5):

```
public static int randomInt(int digits) {
    int minimum = (int) Math.pow(10, digits - 1); // minimum value with 2 digits is 10 (10^1)
    int maximum = (int) Math.pow(10, digits) - 1; // maximum value with 2 digits is 99 (10^2 - 1)
    Random random = new Random();
    return minimum + random.nextInt((maximum - minimum) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply disregard the numbers that are not in the required range. That way your modified pseudo random number generator guarantees that it generates a number in the given range uniformly at random:

```
public class RandomOfDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nd = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int loIn = (int) Math.pow(10, nd-1);
        int hiEx = (int) Math.pow(10, nd);
        Random r = new Random();
        int x;
        do {
            x = r.nextInt(hiEx);
        } while (x < loIn);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int x = loIn + r.nextInt(hiEx - loIn)` would be better.

Comment: Why is that so? I tried with a million iterations and my PRNG does seem to gravitate toward the mean. Maybe I should try more ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would naturally write a method like this:

```
private long generateRandomNumber(int n){
    double tenToN = Math.pow(10, n),
           tenToNMinus1 = Math.pow(10, n-1);
    long randNum = (long) (Math.random() * (tenToN - tenToNMinus1) + tenToNMinus1);
    return randNum;
}
```