# Random in Java often generating same value

Tags: java, android, random

[image]

I'm using this to generate values between `5` to `13`

```
 int randomGeneratedLevelValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5, 13);
```

How to make same matches fewer?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887745/7505436)

Comment: Although your approach is rather clever, there are some disadvantages as well (some of which may result in your issue), it's been described here [Random over ThreadLocalRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396033/random-over-threadlocalrandom)

Comment: So you don't wana random values? same values are pretty normal for such range ... do some math and count probability of same number

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Birthday Paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) predicts that the probability of duplicates in random numbers is much higher than you'd think. For example, it predicts that, with a mere 23 random people, there's a greater than 50% chance of two of them have the same birthday. By the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), it takes 367 people for there to be a 100% chance of a duplicate, but the probability of a duplicate is extremely high even before that.

Here's the probability distribution (from Wikipedia):
[image]

The [rule of thumb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Square_approximation) to approximate the number of numbers you have to generate before the probability of duplicates reaches `sqrt(2m * p(n))`, where `m` is the number of possible random numbers and `p(n)` is the probability that you're looking for. So, for example, if you're generating random numbers in a 50-number range (e.g. if you pick a random number from 100 - 150), you'd only have to generate approximately `sqrt((2 * 50) * 0.5) = 7.07` random numbers before the odds are just as good as not that you have a duplicate. If you generate 8 random numbers within a 50-number range, odds are better than not that'll have a duplicate. (Note that this only works for `p(n)` values of up to 1/2).

In your case, there are 8 possible values for any particular random value (5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), so you only need to generate `sqrt(8) = 2.83` numbers before there's a probability of 50% that you'll have a duplicate. In other words, the Birthday Paradox predicts you only need to generate approximately 3 numbers for the chances to be better than not that you'll have a duplicate.

See also [this Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339125/acceptable-to-rely-on-random-ints-being-unique).

One more point: beware the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy), in which people assume that if you randomly generate, for example, a 10, odds are the next one won't be a 10. Actually, given that you're generating random numbers, the odds of any particular number is 1/8 regardless of what numbers came before. In other words, if you generate a 12, the probability of the next number being a 10 is 1/8. If you generate a 7, the odds of the next number being a 10 is 1/8. If you generate a 10, the probability of the next number being a 10 is still 1/8. Each number is an *independent event* (i.e. the numbers you've generated so far don't influence the probability distribution of future numbers in the least).

**TL;DR** You need to generate much fewer numbers than you think you do before you're likely to start getting duplicates - if you're generating random numbers within a small range of numbers in particular (like you are) the number is particularly low.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to reduce the number of repetitions in a true random number sequence without biasing the random number sequence.

So, for example, in your sequence `10, 5, 12, 12, 13, 13`, the chance that `12` is followed by another `12` is 1 in 9; i.e. the same as the probability of any other number in the range.

Now it is possible that since you are using `Random` / `ThreadLocalRandom` you are seeing the effects of the autocorrelation that is inherent in linear congruential generators.  If so, these effects can be eliminated by using `SecureRandom` instead.  But `SecureRandom` calls are significantly  more expensive.

---

The other approach would be to deliberately bias *against* repetitions; e.g. (pseudo-code)

```
int random = rand.nextInt(...)
if (random == lastRandom) {
     random = rand.nextInt(...);
}
return random;
```

But be careful.  Introducing a bias could have unintended / unexpected consequences.

Comment: what is last number??

Comment: The last random number that you got from your generator.  This is **pseudocode**

Comment: *what is last number??* with `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5, 13)` ? 12 (*nextInt(int least, int bound)
Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed value between the given least value (inclusive) and **bound (exclusive).***)... but you asked *How to make same matches fewer?* and this answer answers that question

Comment: @Selvin - I think the OP is asking what `lastRandom` means in my pseudo code.  But it is really hard to tell.  His question and the comments are very unclear.

Comment: hehe He answers to himself with `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max+1)` that why I thought that *what is last number?* was about what `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5, 13)` returns as last number not `lastRandom` in your code .... *What we've got here is failure to communicate*

Comment: @Selvin - your rationale is plausible ... and we will only know for sure if he explains himself.